# Odata controller returns not complete result. (EDM model)

Tags: api, entity-framework-core, odata, asp.net-core-2.2

**scenario**

I have some entity called *Category* defined in my *EFcontext*. It is clean POCO class. In EFContext *OnModelCreating* method I apply entity configuration. In my startup I configure Odata for my queries and build EDM model based on *Conventional Builder*. My controller inherited from *ODataController*, has *ODataRoutePrefix*, *OdataRoute* and *EnableQuery* attributes.

**Problem**

In my response i received:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://localhost:44362/api/odata/$metadata#Categories",
"value": [
```

It is not mistake. It ends with '['. No error. httpstatus: 200

**odata config**

```
        app.UseMvc(options =>
        {
            options.EnableDependencyInjection();
            options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().Expand().MaxTop(100).SkipToken();
            options.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "api/odata", GetEdmModel());               
        });


        private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        var category = builder.EntitySet<Category>("Categories");
        category.EntityType.HasKey(c => c.Id);

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

**EF CategoryTypeConfiguration**

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> categoryConfiguration)
    {
        categoryConfiguration.ToTable("Categories", QueryEFContext.DefaultSchema);

        categoryConfiguration.HasKey(category => category.Id);

        categoryConfiguration.Property(category => category.Name).IsRequired();
        categoryConfiguration.Property(category => category.Color).IsRequired();
    }
```

**Tried**

It returns proper response when I delete line:

```
 modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CategoryTypeConfiguration());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once encountered this bug. In my case it happened because an error occurred in Entity Framework but the service returned a `200 OK` anyway.

To see if this is the case in your application you could configure Visual Studio to break on all exceptions:

- Click: Debug `->` Windows `->` Exception Settings (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `E`)
- Check: 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions'

Then send your request again and see if any exceptions pop up.

Comment: thank you. In my case, I have forgotten to execute Update-Database (migrations). I am using 2 EF DbContext. First for commands (DDD and migrations) and second for queries (odata). Mappings from command context have not beed executed in database, so my query context with the same mappings has seen wrong data model.